# Insert hero image into a section

Tags: html, css

I would like to append a hero image into an HTML section. But the problem is this image doesn't take the whole page as intended when it is wrapped into a section.

For exemple

```
    <div id="home">
      <div class="text-vcenter">
        <h1>Reunion Qualité</h1>
        <h2>Meeting Manager</h2>
        <svg height="10" width="605">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="611" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:3" />
        </svg>
        <h3>Namur-Belgium</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Will work, but

```
<div>
    <div id="home">
      <div class="text-vcenter">
        <h1>Reunion Qualité</h1>
        <h2>Meeting Manager</h2>
        <svg height="10" width="605">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="611" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:3" />
        </svg>
        <h3>Namur-Belgium</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Won't. Why ? How can i fix this ?

Here is the CSS linked regarding the Hero image :

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

#home {
  background: url(../img/qualite_01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  color: #f6f8f8;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the second example isn't working is because you haven't specified the height of the first div (the div that wraps the #hero div). So just add the following rule to your CSS:

```
body div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

A percentage height defines the height as a percentage of containing block's height (see [MDN article about height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [MDN article about percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)). #home's height was set to 100%, but its containing block didn't have a height specified. In the first example, on the other hand, #home's containing element is body, which has a height of 100% specified.

Comment: You are right, this is the reason why. Now i'm having another problem. The reason why i wanted to wrap it into another div was to be able to append it with Jquery when i was on the wanted page. If i set the height of the parent div (the target of the Jquery function) to 100%, then i'll still have a white 100% blank space on every pages :/.

Comment: If you post a codepen with you JavaScript, HTML, and CSS I could help you more, but without that I wouldn't be able to provide any recommendations on what you could do.

Comment: Yes probably because of the image he can't find because of the relative path

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the outer `<div>` tag you are wrapping it all in. Naturally, a `<div>` won't take up the entire width of the body. An example snippet is below. With the border on it, we can see that it does not take up the full width of the body. Why is it needed to wrap the working solution in an extra `<div>`?

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
        Some Text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second snippet to show changes plus adding margin and padding equal to 0, which removes whitespace around the page

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#outerDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#home {
  background: url(../img/qualite_01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  color: #f6f8f8;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="home">
      <div class="text-vcenter">
        <h1>Reunion Qualité</h1>
        <h2>Meeting Manager</h2>
        <svg height="10" width="605">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="611" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:3" />
        </svg>
        <h3>Namur-Belgium</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to wrap it into an extra div because i need to append it with Jquery only when i'm on the home page.

Comment: I would suggest trying to give that div a class or an ID and adding it and add CSS like .outerDiv {height:100%; width:100%}. Just to match what you have declared for home and body

Comment: Yes it works by doing that, but i have a 100% white space on every pages then :/.

Comment: Add this - {margin:0; padding: 0;} to your html, body

Comment: It doesn't change anything :/

Comment: I added a second snippet that shows the white space around the page is gone now. Is that what you mean by 100% white space?

Comment: In fact the reason why i want to wrap the hero image html code into another div is to be able to append it with Jquery only when i'm on the home page. When i'll be on another page, nothing will be appended into that div and so nothing will show on screen regarding that section. If i set the height of that other div to 100%, then i'll have a 100% white blank space on every pages.